# What is this happned to my furniture

Tags: water-protection, wood-drying, moisture, physical-protection

I have a closed room where I keep some furniture which is made up of engineered wood. By closed, I mean I dont keep windows open. Also in that room, I keep wet cloths to dry on cloths drying stand below fan (which is ON all time). The room is quite small. After some days, I realized something is wrong with my furniture. Some white/yellowish colored deposits were found on its edges as can be seen in below pics. When I cleaned, the edges were looking normal and undamaged. So, it doesnt seem to be termite. What is it, a fungus due to moisture in the room or anything else? Is it something to worry about? Should I do something to avoid it in future? I am thinking to keep my exhaust fan ON all time too. Will it help to get rid of moisture (if it is indeed happening due to moisture)?

PS: I have no experience in woodworking.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably not mould, and maybe related to you using this room as a drying room. But without knowing the relative humidity of the rest of the dwelling, and your general climate it's hard to speculate. This is probably off-topic for WW.SE, unfortunately. Maybe a more immediate forum like Reddit might help?

Comment: @jdv I disagree that it’s not mold. Even if it’s not, It’s still almost certainly related to the higher humidity. Running the exhaust fan more should help though it shouldn’t need to be kept on all the time. I agree it’s off topic here and will probably be closed.

Comment: @T.M.running the exhaust won't make a difference if the RH of the rest of the house is as high. I have never seen white mould -- usually mould abatement is for the black stuff. It could be a fungus, which is splitting hairs given how mould is basically the same kingdom. I suppose this could be some specific fungus/mould that is eating the glue that was used for the veneering. I know that most modern glues are made not to support this sort of growth, but it used to be a problem.

Comment: whatever it is, will it damage the furniture in long run to greater extent (given that, as I said, after cleaning it, furniture look absolutely intact) For idea about general climate here, I live in Mumbai.

Comment: To be clear, "I have never seen white mould" on non-food material. Mould and fungus comes in all sorts of interesting colours, but the typical household mould related to humidity where I live is the black stuff. Things might be different in Mumbai, of course. Depending on how new this furniture is, this might just be water activated polyurethane glue reacting to higher humidity. There is no way to tell from the photos.

Comment: was thinking if de humidifier can help?